# Sorting a dataframe based on multiple columns - Sorting issue

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe, multiple-columns, columnsorting

i have a data frame as below

```
Provider.Number Hospital.Name   State   Mortality
210001  MERITUS MEDICAL CENTER  MD  12.5
210002  UNIVERSITY OF MARYLAND MEDICAL CENTER   MD  12.7
210003  PRINCE GEORGES HOSPITAL CENTER  MD  13
210004  HOLY CROSS HOSPITAL MD  9.6
210005  FREDERICK MEMORIAL HOSPITAL MD  9.8
210006  HARFORD MEMORIAL HOSPITAL   MD  11.5
210007  SAINT JOSEPH MEDICAL CENTER MD  9.5
210008  MERCY MEDICAL CENTER INC    MD  11.2
210009  JOHNS HOPKINS HOSPITAL, THE MD  10.2
210011  SAINT AGNES HOSPITAL    MD  11.1
210012  SINAI HOSPITAL OF BALTIMORE MD  9.7
210013  BON SECOURS HOSPITAL    MD  9.6
210015  MEDSTAR FRANKLIN SQUARE MEDICAL CENTER  MD  9.3
210016  WASHINGTON ADVENTIST HOSPITAL   MD  11
210017  GARRETT COUNTY MEMORIAL HOSPITAL    MD  13.5
210018  MEDSTAR MONTGOMERY MEDICAL CENTER   MD  9.3
210019  PENINSULA REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER   MD  10.6
210022  SUBURBAN HOSPITAL   MD  9.9
210023  ANNE ARUNDEL MEDICAL CENTER MD  12
210024  MEDSTAR UNION MEMORIAL HOSPITAL MD  11.3
210027  WESTERN MARYLAND REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER    MD  12.6
210028  MEDSTAR SAINT MARY'S HOSPITAL   MD  13.1
210029  JOHNS HOPKINS BAYVIEW MEDICAL CENTER    MD  10.7
210030  CHESTER RIVER HOSPITAL CENTER   MD  11.2
210032  UNION HOSPITAL OF CECIL COUNTY  MD  9.9
210033  CARROLL HOSPITAL CENTER MD  9.7
210034  MEDSTAR HARBOR HOSPITAL MD  9.2
210035  CIVISTA MEDICAL CENTER  MD  14.2
210037  MEMORIAL HOSPITAL AT EASTON MD  10.6
210038  MARYLAND GENERAL  HOSPITAL  MD  10.8
210039  CALVERT MEMORIAL HOSPITAL   MD  10.1
210040  NORTHWEST HOSPITAL CENTER   MD  12.6
210043  BALTIMORE WASHINGTON  MEDICAL CENTER    MD  12.7
210044  GREATER BALTIMORE MEDICAL CENTER    MD  7.4
210045  EDWARD MCCREADY MEMORIAL HOSPITAL   MD  12.9
210048  HOWARD COUNTY GENERAL HOSPITAL  MD  10.1
210049  UPPER CHESAPEAKE MEDICAL CENTER MD  12.9
210051  DOCTORS'  COMMUNITY HOSPITAL    MD  11
210054  SOUTHERN MARYLAND HOSPITAL CENTER   MD  11.7
210055  LAUREL REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER  MD  10.6
210056  MEDSTAR GOOD SAMARITAN HOSPITAL MD  8.4
210057  SHADY GROVE ADVENTIST HOSPITAL  MD  11.7
210060  FORT WASHINGTON HOSPITAL    MD  11
210061  ATLANTIC GENERAL HOSPITAL   MD  10.8
21020F  VA MARYLAND HEALTHCARE SYSTEM - BALTIMORE   MD  12.6
```

i want to sort the DF based on mortality column and then alphabetical order of Hospital column to handle ties.

I tired using different sort functions like

```
sorted <- work[order(work$Mortality,work$Hosptial),]
```

or

```
with(work, order(Mortality, Hospital))
```

but the final sorted outcome is wrong.
The output i got is

```
Hosptial    State   Mortality
CALVERT MEMORIAL HOSPITAL   MD  10.1
HOWARD COUNTY GENERAL HOSPITAL  MD  10.1
JOHNS HOPKINS HOSPITAL, THE MD  10.2
LAUREL REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER  MD  10.6
MEMORIAL HOSPITAL AT EASTON MD  10.6
PENINSULA REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER   MD  10.6
JOHNS HOPKINS BAYVIEW MEDICAL CENTER    MD  10.7
ATLANTIC GENERAL HOSPITAL   MD  10.8
MARYLAND GENERAL  HOSPITAL  MD  10.8
DOCTORS'  COMMUNITY HOSPITAL    MD  11
FORT WASHINGTON HOSPITAL    MD  11
WASHINGTON ADVENTIST HOSPITAL   MD  11
SAINT AGNES HOSPITAL    MD  11.1
CHESTER RIVER HOSPITAL CENTER   MD  11.2
MERCY MEDICAL CENTER INC    MD  11.2
MEDSTAR UNION MEMORIAL HOSPITAL MD  11.3
HARFORD MEMORIAL HOSPITAL   MD  11.5
SHADY GROVE ADVENTIST HOSPITAL  MD  11.7
SOUTHERN MARYLAND HOSPITAL CENTER   MD  11.7
ANNE ARUNDEL MEDICAL CENTER MD  12
MERITUS MEDICAL CENTER  MD  12.5
NORTHWEST HOSPITAL CENTER   MD  12.6
VA MARYLAND HEALTHCARE SYSTEM - BALTIMORE   MD  12.6
WESTERN MARYLAND REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER    MD  12.6
BALTIMORE WASHINGTON  MEDICAL CENTER    MD  12.7
UNIVERSITY OF MARYLAND MEDICAL CENTER   MD  12.7
EDWARD MCCREADY MEMORIAL HOSPITAL   MD  12.9
UPPER CHESAPEAKE MEDICAL CENTER MD  12.9
PRINCE GEORGES HOSPITAL CENTER  MD  13
MEDSTAR SAINT MARY'S HOSPITAL   MD  13.1
GARRETT COUNTY MEMORIAL HOSPITAL    MD  13.5
CIVISTA MEDICAL CENTER  MD  14.2
GREATER BALTIMORE MEDICAL CENTER    MD  7.4
MEDSTAR GOOD SAMARITAN HOSPITAL MD  8.4
MEDSTAR HARBOR HOSPITAL MD  9.2
MEDSTAR FRANKLIN SQUARE MEDICAL CENTER  MD  9.3
MEDSTAR MONTGOMERY MEDICAL CENTER   MD  9.3
SAINT JOSEPH MEDICAL CENTER MD  9.5
BON SECOURS HOSPITAL    MD  9.6
HOLY CROSS HOSPITAL MD  9.6
CARROLL HOSPITAL CENTER MD  9.7
SINAI HOSPITAL OF BALTIMORE MD  9.7
FREDERICK MEMORIAL HOSPITAL MD  9.8
SUBURBAN HOSPITAL   MD  9.9
UNION HOSPITAL OF CECIL COUNTY  MD  9.9
```

Function that gets 2 arguments:

1. state(check the original CSV data)
2. heart attack/ heat failure/ Pneumonia

My complete code is

```
best <- function(states,outcomes)  
{  

    #patterns is obtained to use them in the regex function 
    patterns<-paste("^Hospital.*",outcomes, sep="")
     Readcsv<-read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv", check.names = F)
    columnname<-colnames(Readcsv)
    #regex operation going on
    regex1<-grep(patterns,columnname,ignore.case=TRUE, value = T)
    #another regex operation
    Extracted<-grep("Mortality",regex1,ignore.case=TRUE, value = T)
    #extract dataframe based on the state and final extracted column name using the regex function
    dfe<-subset(Readcsv, Readcsv$State == states & Readcsv[[Extracted]]!="Not Available")
     #create a vector
    b<-c("Hospital Name","State", Extracted)
    #extract only those columns seen in the vector
    work<-dfe[,b]
    #change column name
    colnames(work)<-c("Hosptial","State","Mortality")
    # stuck after this point
    Ascorder<-work[with(work, order(Mortality, Hosptial)),]

}
```

I am relatively new to Stack overflow, please mind my formatting issue. I would like to understand where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dplyr for this:

```
require(dplyr)
work <- work %>%
    arrange(Mortality, Hospital)
```

I couldn't test it because you didn't give a reproducible example of your data, but it should do the trick.

Comment: when i tried to apply this directly on the filtered data frame the sorting was not in the correct order but when i exported the filtered DF in to a CSV and read it back again and implemented the function,it worked fine. But anyways, its working now. Thanks for the solution.